# SQL Server Stored Procedure Syntax Error

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure that returns a deposit record for a specific person, the number of deposits for that person and the row number of that deposit for that person. The parameter `@personID` is always supplied the correct personID; however `@SpecificRow` is either 0 (meaning: return most recent deposit) or a row number (meaning:return record at this specific row).

Script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [schema].[procedure]
    @personID varchar(5),
    @SpecificRow int,
    @RowNumber INT OUTPUT,
    @RowCount INT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('#TempSortedDeposits') IS NOT NULL 
       DROP Table #TempSortedDeposits

    -- get all deposits with record number into temp file for specific personID
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date ASC) AS RecordNo, *
    INTO 
        #TempSortedDeposits
    FROM 
        persons.Deposits
    WHERE 
        personID = @personID

    -- get record count in file
    SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(personID)
    FROM persons.Deposits
    WHERE personID = @personID 

    IF @SpecificRow = 0 --get most recent record
        SET @RowNumber = @RowCount;
    ELSE
        --get record by rownumber
        SET @RowNumber = @SpecificRow;

    SELECT * 
    FROM #TempSortedDeposits 
    WHERE RecordNo = ­@RowNumber
END
```

When I try running the alter statement, I get the following error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure procedure, Line 33 [Batch Start Line 9]
>   Incorrect syntax near '­'.

Any insight?

Thanks.

Comment: check what was passed to the param @personID?

Comment: @FullMoonFisher this shouldn't cause an error on compile, just execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted this line `SELECT * FROM #TempSortedDeposits WHERE RecordNo = @RowNumber` and manually re-type it then it worked.

This is because the error occurs due to copy and paste. That result to pasted code **contains unprintable characters** like d non-braking spaces.

Comment: Thanks. How did you identify that line as being the problem?

Comment: because of this error "Incorrect syntax near '­'. is almost always invoked by unprintable characters as nothing printed out after "near".

Answer (score 1):

Just a side note... your `#TempSortedDeposits` table  dropping like you think it is.

Here's a quick example:

```
create table #TempSortedDeposits (i int)
insert into #TempSortedDeposits
values
(1)

IF OBJECT_ID('#TempSortedDeposits') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempSortedDeposits
select * from #TempSortedDeposits
```

If you run this the first time, it will return 1 when it shouldn't, because it should have been dropped. On the second run (same connection) you will get this error, showing you that the table still exists and wasn't dropped:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 6, Line 2 There is already an object named
>   '#TempSortedDeposits' in the database.

To fix this, change the syntax to:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempSortedDeposits') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempSortedDeposits
```

Here is a test

```
create table #TempSortedDeposits (i int)
insert into #TempSortedDeposits
values
(1)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempSortedDeposits') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TempSortedDeposits
select * from #TempSortedDeposits
```

If you first manually drop the table (since we created it with the last run) and then run this, you will get the error message:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 7 Invalid object name
>   '#TempSortedDeposits'.

Which means the select failed, thus showing that the table was in fact dropped.

Answer (score 1):

I have removed the extra character present in below line and re execute this proc. Line is 
SELECT * FROM #TempSortedDeposits WHERE RecordNo = @RowNumber